# Getting Error while Scanning a Java project in SonarScanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.
        at org.sonar.java.classpath.ClasspathForMain.init(ClasspathForMain.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.classpath.AbstractClasspath.getElements(AbstractClasspath.java:317)
        at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:175)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.<init>(JavaFrontend.java:88)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSensor.execute(JavaSensor.java:108)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:79)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:378)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:347)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Are you using any build tool like maven?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very specific.  Is there something about that error message that you don't understand?

The SonarQube scan is typically done during a build, after the source files are compiled to class files, so they are available in the same workspace.